# Is it possible to lose a badge once you earned it?

Tags: discussion, badges

Can you lose a badge once you earned it?

Think for example of the "Favorite Question" badge (earned when one of your questions is favorited by 25 users). If one of my questions is favorited 25 times, I understand I automatically earn this badge but, what would happen if one of these 25 users undid their favorite vote? Would I lose my badge?

Comment: You can only loose tag badges.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In general, if no foul play caused a badge to be awarded (say, a badge for good answer but due to sock-puppet upvotes), even if the conditions that caused a badge to be earned are no longer true, the badge will remain.

We don't revoke badges, unless there was fraud involved in getting them in the first place.

The above is true for "regular" badges - tag badges are a different matter.

Comment: @Oded: Do you guard against giving out a "good answer"-award twice for the same answer, regardless how much time passed between the first and second time the answer fulfilled the condition? The same for all those other awards which can be earned multiple times?

Comment: @Deduplicator - if a badge was already awarded for an answer, it will not be awarded again for the same one, so yes, we do have such guards.