# Remove undeserved badges

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, deleted-questions, voting-fraud

By way of background, some time ago I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848490/passing-multiple-queries-to-a-view). Before OP edited it, the question was just *"There is some issues"* and a code dump. I voted it down and left a comment. A little later I came back, saw the question now included that the issue was a *"Null Ponter Exception"*.

I perhaps should have marked it as a duplicate; but, after a few comments, I added an answer. OP shortly after marked the answer as accepted, and in a thread to another answer, I commented that I had down voted OP's question with the reason why.

I guess that comment was not well received because next time I logged in:

1. I had a message that the community had rejected an attempt by the OP
   to deface my answer,
2. OP removed the acceptance of my answer,
3. OP had added their own answer, plagiarizing mine, but adding a whole
   lot of irrelevant code (`using` statements etc)

A little later I came across [this (now deleted) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854385/how-to-bind-multiple-quries-to-view/28854450#28854450), which was an exact duplicate of OP's question, and OP had added the identical answer (which was marked as accepted). The user who posted the question only become a member that same day. At the same time I noticed that OP's rep had gone from zero to over 80 with all votes occurring in a few seconds (since reversed).

I flagged it for moderator intervention as a case of voting fraud. It took some time, but eventually the new users question, and OP's self answer to the original post were removed.

Now when you go to the [new user's profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4632030/jibin-mathew?tab=profile), it states *"This user hasn't posted... yet."* (and the activity tab shows no questions or answers) but the user has 2 badges, **Scholar** (ask a question and accept an answer) and **Student** (first question with a score of 1 or more).

Should those badges also be removed, and is it a bug that the badges were not removed?

---

Edit:

I don't consider this a duplicate of [Losing a badge in StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261258/losing-a-badge-in-stackoverflow) since its accepted answer states *"We don't revoke badges, unless there was fraud involved"*. In this case, I believe there was voting fraud involved.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it a bug, since badges in general never get removed once awarded, even if you fall back below the threshold required to earn it. In this case, though, if it were serious enough of a problem, would be a place where an exception and manual intervention could take place (if that's even possible)

Comment: @KevinB I could have sworn that tag badges are recalculated and potentially revoked (and later re-awarded)

Comment: I'm not sure about tag badges, though it could be pretty annoying (and pointless in some cases) for that kind of recalculation to occur for some of the other badges.

Comment: "Populist" would be a really annoying one to lose due to recalculation... "Yeah, I know you earned "Populist" when your answer had 25 and their answer had 11 score, but now that your answer has 1,000 score and their answer has 525 score, we have to take that badge away.

Comment: @nhgrif It seems like the solution is to revoke the badge in cases of fraud, but not simply because a user no longer meets a given criterion.

Answer (score 21):

In principle badges are at risk of being removed in case of fraud, but I don't think there should be an automatic expectation that moderators or administrators should put in the time to actually do it.

In this case "Scholar" and "Student" are so unimportant and simple to get that it really doesn't seem worth the effort. They are really just there as "introductory" badges for the site.

There are probably hundreds of examples of them being got fraudulently and the time needed to track them down and deal with them could be better spent on many other things.

Comment: I agree that they are insignificant badges. Just seems odd that the profile page states the user has not asked any questions yet has 2 badges associated with asking a question.