# Change the "Looks OK" Text in the LQP Queue

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review-queues, low-quality-posts

As has been discussed many times before according to both [community consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) and [SE staff opinions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318020/so-this-is-an-answer/318022#comment316461_318022), the NAA and VLQ flags are not intended to delete actual (albeit bad) attempts to answer. However when you hover over the "Looks OK" option in the queue, it displays the following text:

> this answer doesn't seem to be low quality

That text suggests that being merely low quality (== bad, but still an answer) would be grounds for deletion. Its only adding to the already rampant confusion in the queue.

I propose changing this text to something more unambiguous like:

> This seems to be an actual answer or at least an attempt at one.

To make it clear that LQP Queue deletion is not a substitute for something merely downvote-worthy.

Comment: Maybe the real problem is trying to judge people's *intent* when posting answers.

Comment: @CodyGray Im not trying to rehash the 1000x done discussion in this thread, but merely mention something that bugs me and seems to be out of line with established consensus on the matter.

Comment: Well, the name "Low Quality Posts" is also going to be a source of cognitive friction then. I smell another [feature-request].

Comment: @CodyGray Perhaps, but I think its worth changing because it makes its purpose alot clearer to reviewers that don't frequent meta all the time.

Comment: I guess thats that then. Shog, can you shed some light on why you declined this?

Answer (score 3):

When you're done reading hover-text, read the rest of the text associated with that review queue:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now follow the instructions.

Comment: that looks worse "Looks OK if nothing is wrong with this answer" "BUT ITS A WRONG ANSWER"

Comment: Is there an epidemic of myopia afflicting folks today? There's only maybe 7 lines of text here, read it *all* and stop trying to build a comprehensive theory of review based on whichever single line your eye lands on first.

Comment: You must be new here. No one reads instructions on the Internet.

Comment: Amusingly, the folks who don't read the instructions are rarely a problem; we adjust the thresholds for action based on what appears to reflect consensus, and shit just works. It's the folks who *start* to read the instructions and then hyperanalyze each word who are a pain.

Comment: Look, the only way you get everybody happy is if the text says "delete this", "don't delete this" and "I see your point". I'm on the fence about the last one, between "what is this guy smoking?" and "I don't want to touch this". #serious

Comment: No, that will not make anyone happy @Braiam. It will shift the discussion away from "is this low quality?" toward "is this something that should be deleted?", which we'd then define based on perceived intent and quality, which would make the handful of people who spend all their time on meta happy but be absolutely worthless for the folks who just have a few minutes a day to review. So the next request would be for more specific guidance in review and we'd begin this whole cycle again.

Comment: Look what I would do Shog: I A/B test a change in the text (for science), make a meta post saying that I would be A/B testing, get empiric data, and then either admit I was wrong or have proof I was right. But I imagine we both pursue different objectives.

Comment: A/B testing isn't magic, @Braiam. You need a goal. What's our goal here? More deletion? Less? Different things being deleted? More editing? Less? Without a clear objective, an A/B test just tells you that people react differently to different UIs; it doesn't tell you whether one is preferable to the other. There's also the problem that [announcing a behavioral test can really mess with the results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawthorne_effect)...

Comment: Also, kinda sick of all this bike-shed discussion while the real problem staring us in the face is 800+ items in the LQ review queue. We've got this inland salt-sea thing happening where folks get too twisted up about nuances to make a decision, and y'all want *more nuance*. If you can't smell it 1000ft away, it's OK; if your eyes water, delete. If you can fix it, edit. It's not that hard, and the world won't end if you OK an answer that's less awesome than it possibly could be. Get rid of the piles of garbage, let voters do the landscaping.