# Is an answer that boils down to "Google this algorithm" acceptable on SO?

Tags: discussion, answers

I was surprised that a moderator declined my "Not an answer" flag [for this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51229380/8881141). In their defense, it has to be mentioned that at the time of the decision the OP mysteriously accepted this as the solution, while complaining that it is not a good solution for the problem.
I had a look [at these guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) and I stand by my flag. For me, an answer that boils down to "Google this algorithm" is a link in disguise. But maybe I am mistaken and this kind of reply is indeed an acceptable answer on SO.
Any input for future reference is most welcome.

Comment: If it was just *Google an algorithm* it would qualify for a rude flag. The answer you linked to doesn't contain that phrase. It is surrounded with some valuable bits which makes it an answer. If you don't think the answer is useful, down vote. If the question ask for off-site resources, close vote the question.

Comment: @rene I have modified my description. It really boils down to "Google CNN lane detection" in my eyes but seemingly  you and  the moderator disagree.

Comment: Would not recommend NAA-flagging anything except "Thanks"-answers and the like. Bad flag, 0/10. Also please note that the OP mysteriously accepting an answer does not mean much if the OP is a new member, as they often times are under the Impression that a bad answer still warrants an accept if it's the only answer.

Comment: @Seth But a link to a paper with a description of CNN lane detection would be worth an NAA flag? Strange.

Comment: @Mr.T "NAA" = Does not attempt to answer the question. "Google X" is an attempt, albeit a bad one. Answers in that style are better off with a "VLQ" flag.

Comment: The value in that answer is *CNN lane detection*. If the answer says *You're looking for a technique called CNN lane detection*, would you still flag as NAA?

Comment: @rene This is obviously the reason for disagreement here. You and others think "CNN should be your tool" is a valid answer, I think this is so general that it doesn't qualify. I wouldn't answer a question how to create a violin plot in Python with "Google seaborn" but I get it that it is on SO enough to disqualify for an NAA flag. Thanks for clarifying. The difference to a "Here is a link to a CNN paper", which qualifies for an NAA flag, is still unclear, though.

Comment: If you feel an answer doesn't qualify it should be down voted, not flagged. Flagging isn't the right tool to get rid of answers that don't add much value. Find a 20K-er to delete vote such answers.

Comment: I think you're having an XY problem here. The real issue is, why is the question not yet closed as either lacking a MCVE or too broad? Why did two people upvote a question that boils down to "I'm doing a CV task and it's not working"? Of course such a question attracts less than stellar answers (the code dump one isn't much better than the "google it" one), but the _question_ is the problem, not the answers.

Comment: @l4mpi Good point. The correlation between the quality of the answers and the quality of the question is always astonishing.

Comment: Yikes.  Recommending a neural network is good advice, that makes it an answer.  Surely nobody here would want him to hurt himself badly.

Comment: @Mr.T - is it good practice to allow a person to edit a question so as to make any answers redundant?  If so, would it be good practice to show those later edits when they then question the "incorrectness" of your supplied answer?

Comment: Bad questions tend to generate bad answers. The real issue here is "is a question that boils down to "what algorighm to use" acceptable for SO?"

Comment: In my opinion, answers that tell you "You're barking up the wrong tree." need more of an explanation than "Everybody is doing it this other way these days.". There may well be specific reasons the OP is choosing the algorithm they are that aren't immediately obvious.

Comment: As I was advised here, and have come to accept, anything that can lead the OP to a solution is an acceptable answer:    https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318020/so-this-is-an-answer

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's not a *good* answer, but it *is* an answer. This is similar to the following example from [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer?s=1%7C113.7356):

> See, this **is** an answer:
>
> > You probably want a [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)
>
> Don't get me wrong, it's still a bad answer...

Your example is very much like that (though I'd say not quite as bad as that). It boils down to "Use a CNN," a suggestion to read up on recent lane detection projects and academic papers, and a recommendation that the OP get a GPU card and start training (training because CNN stands for "convolutional neural network").

That's definitely an answer, just not a very good one. I'm not qualified to judge the question, but it doesn't seem like a good question, so just not answering, voting to close, and moving on would probably be useful. If it's an okay question, then providing some reasoning behind why CNN would be a good choice, perhaps citing a couple of those academic papers, etc., would strengthen it a lot. (The answerer ended up doing *some* of that in a follow-on comment.)

Comment: I understand but feel uncomfortable with it. A link to a tutorial that actually tells the OP what to do is not an answer and will probably be deleted but telling the OP to look for a tutorial is an answer. Grey area, I guess.

Comment: @Mr.T - No, a link to a tutorial would be an answer too, provided it said what it was linking to, see again the example above from "another castle", which links to `FileInputStream`'s documentation. So for instance, "See [this tutorial](http://example.com) on using a CNN for lane detection." would be an answer, too (not a very good one). "See [this tutorial](http://example.com)." would not be, for the reasons explained in "another castle."

Comment: But this is imho not the reality in the review queue. Not according to most reviewers. And not according to the audits, which you would most likely fail when accepting a link only answer.

Comment: @Mr.T - Again: These examples aren't link-only. My final example in the comment above is link-only. The others are not.

Comment: When you remove all links, does the answer still offer some value/info? The "_See this tutorial on using a CNN for lane detection._" does (yet very low); while the "_See this tutorial._" doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Google `https://www.google.com.au/search?q=is+a+link+a+question`

---

Sorry bad example.

In my limited time on SO. I have had some great lengthy answers, with examples, with links, that answered my question completely.

I have also had questions, with short answers that pointed me in the right direction to work it out myself.

---

Although I can't see your answer now, considering it is an OpenCV question any point in the right direction would be helpful when your stuck.
I've personally been stuck for days on builing OpenCV projects, and a nudge makes all the difference.

---

So to answer your question. Yes. "Google ..." is an answer. (As long as the answer doesn't just rephrase the question)

A good or bad answer, is up to the SO community, and of course the OP.

**Edit: additional thought**

I should say "google this" is the new "use a search engine" or even "open an encyclopedia".

It is a term used to say, use this information to do some research in.. google/encyclopedia.

It is completely different from saying, look at this tutorial. - NOT AN ANSWER!

The best reason: 3 months later the site could be gone. You just have a dead link.

If you post the solution, and then a link as reference. Yes, an answer.